# Contrast Function in a time dependent cox model with interactions

Tags: cox-model, contrasts

I have a time-dependent cox model with three variables, each of which interacts with the other two. So my final model is:

fit12<-coxph(formula = Surv(data\$TimeIn, data\$Timeout, data\$Status) ~ data\$Year+data\$Life_Stg+data\$prev.tb +data\$prev.tb*data\$Life_Stg + data\$Year*data\$Life_Stg + data\$Year*data\$prev.tb + frailty(data\$Natal_Group), data = data)

For my variables, there are 3 categories of year, three of year, and prev.tb is a binary variable. Because of the interactions, when I present the results, I want to present the Hazard ratio, 95% CI, and p value for each combination of the three variables. How do I get R to give me these values please?

I think that the contrast function does this for other models but does not work for coxph?